Why does pasting something with angle brackets into GNU Screen not work in Alacritty?
pasting this into screen
wg pubkey < ~/.ssh/wireguard.t520.private.key > ~/.ssh/wireguard.t520.public.key

.. results in this:
~/.ssh/wireguard.t520.private.key > ~/.ssh/wireguard.t520.public.keywg pubkey

I know it looks weird, but that's the result. It's the angle bracket ">" that causes this.
This must be some kind of known bug?;) I think I found some references on this once, but I forgot where.

I'm using Alacritty terminal and I paste with keyboard shortcut and mouse.
I fired up gnome-terminal and it seems it works there, so this must be related to Alacritty.
I also tried xterm and it works there as well, so it's definitely Alacritty that is the culprit.


How are you pasting? Middle click? Right click -> paste? Ctrl+ins? Ctrl+V? From the shell's kill ring (Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+Y)? Does this happen no matter how you paste? And what is your PS1 variable? Does it make a difference if you run PS1='$ ' and then try to paste?

Does it happen when pasting into a shell in particular? Is it better if you paste into e.g. a text editor or a cat process running on the terminal? And should we understand it works better if screen isn't running in the middle? Could you also tell us which terminal emulator you are running?
